# Can´t change cell color in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've a simple form with a datagridview showing values from a ms sql table.
I want that values over 400 in column of name "dc" become red (FONT IN RED).
I've tried it over and over but I can´t get it done. Here's the code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    int cellval = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["dc"].Value);
    if (cellval > 400)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        MessageBox.Show("O valor da célula é " + cellval, "WLic2010", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

Funiest, the thing of the MessageBox really proves that it understands my request as it only pops with the values over 400.

Help please!!

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the style of a Row, not the cell (DataGridViewCell).

```
row.Cells["dc"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: and indeed, the font color is 'ForeColor'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Use the "Style" property ->

```
DataGridView1.Item(ColumnIndex, RowIndex).Style.BackColor = Color
DataGridView1.Item(ColumnIndex, RowIndex).Style.ForeColor = Color
```

or

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color
DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.ForeColor = Color
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: DataGridView1.Item don't exist

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `CellFormatting` event, there you can check the value of the current cell and then change the `BackColor`

Answer (score 0):

To swap the font color, you need alter the `ForeColor` property, try this way:

```
row.Cells["dc"].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be solved if you use DataGridViewCell.Style.ForeColor, instead of DefaultCellStyle.BackColor.

Comment: DataGridViewCell is the name of the type. See the answer @stekkie provided; that should solve your problem. HTH.